# Accessing a file in edge node from spark application in yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

We had a scenario to read a time stamp stored in local file system of edge node from a spark application and after some computations updated time stamp need to be stored back in the same file system.

This application can access the file while running in yarn-client mode but unable to locate the file while running in yarn-cluster mode and the job has been failed stating "FileNotFound Exception"

**How can we access a file for Read/Write from a spark application running in yarn-cluster mode.**

What i had already tried:

- specifying complete file uri including hostname
- --files option (i guess this work only for read operation but not for writing)

Comment: Because the driver can spawn anywhere in cluster mode. Make sure you read write from a distributed file system, like HDFS.

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for this. i also facing the same challenge.